# Unable to import multiple CSS file in react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to import to import different css files, for different elements in a react app. But it is not importing. What did I do wrong?

recipe.js

```
import React from "react";
import style from "style.modules.css";

const Recipe = ({ title, calories, image, ingredients }) => {
  return (
    <div className={style.recipe}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <ol>
        {ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
          <li>{ingredient.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ol>
      <p>Calories={calories}</p>
      <img className={style.image} src={image} alt=''></img>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Recipe;
```

style.modules.css

```
.recipe{
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgb(71, 71, 71);
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background: white;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 40%;
}

.image{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:  100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

What I want it to look like, [image]

What I am getting, [image]

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to see what styles/CSS rules are applied, or overridden, etc?

Comment: Ctrl Shift I and you will see that classes are not applied. If you want to use, you will have to do 'image' and 'recipe'.

Comment: Check if the import path is correct.

Comment: It may not matter but css module files usually take the form `style.module.css` not `style.modules.css`. Try renaming your file and your import. It maybe webpack being awkward.

Comment: @Netranjit, First, find out where CSS Class is applied (ex, .recipe). If there is no duplicate used, check the import path also. and... make sure your component is applied as you intended. :)

Comment: Seems to do this kind of thing, `Webpack` needs to be configured with `ExtractTextPlugin`. It’s not a default feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css file name does matter, it should be [name].module.css.

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./style.module.css";
```

There is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-component-demo-ddnks?file=/src/components/Recipe.js) for reference.

And the details are in:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: I tried doing your way, getting this reply

./src/component/Recipe.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './style/module.css' in 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\recipe\src\component'

Comment: What is the file structure?